# TypeError, cannot read property 0 of undefined

Tags: javascript

I am trying to return all the values in the array to an object, and the value for each key in the object would be based on how many times they appear in the array.
When I try to run it I get the error message "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"
Above the error message it is also written
`if (result.arr[i] === undefined) {`

```
  let result = {}
  let arr = [0, 4, 4, 5, 6, 2, 1]
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (result.arr[i] === undefined) {
      result.arr[i] = arr[i]
    } else {
      result.arr[i] ++
    }
  }
```

Comment: result.arr is undefined. Did you mean to initialize with `let result = { arr: [] };`?

Comment: just use `arr[i]`

Comment: `result.arr` doesn't exist. `result` has no properties. `result` and `arr` are separate objects. Just use `arr` by itself, without the prefix. In your code, `result` appears to have no purpose

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is access the property that is called 'arr' on the object results. That property does not exist therefore you get an undefined error.

Try this instead:

```js
let result = {}
let arr = [0, 4, 4, 5, 6, 2, 1]
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (result[arr[i]] === undefined) {
    result[arr[i]] = 1
  } else {
    result[arr[i]] ++
  }
}
```

Comment: This changes the meaning of what the code does

Comment: @ADyson no it doesn't. Reread the question and you will see what the OP was trying to achieve

Comment: I'm trying to understand what happens in this code that you wrote. What is it that your code does differently

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign an `arr` property to your `result` object when you define the object:

```js
let result = { arr: [ ] },
    arr = [0, 4, 4, 5, 6, 2, 1];
    
for( let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) 
{
  if( ! result.arr[i] ) 
  {
    result.arr[i] = arr[i]
  } 
  else 
  {
    result.arr[i]++;
  }
}

console.log(result);
```